Need to defer the `name` variable in a Bash script
How to defer the name variable in our Bash script so that it expands correctly within quotes in the loop, in such e.g:
name='*'
curate() {
  local e=
  for e in $(export HOME='/home/me'; echo /home/me/Downloads/\${name}.$1)
  do
    [ -e "$e" ] && echo "$e"
  done
}

curate() c

name=foo
curate() c

as it didn't work.
Please help in clear way

curate() c - Sidenote, functions are called simply by invoking their names, i.e. without ().

Please edit your question and add your desired output (no description) for that sample input.

What do you expect setting HOME in your command substitution to accomplsh for you?

What do you expect the echo command in that same process substitution to accomplish for you, especially given that you are escaping the first $?

The result of a command substitution is not subject to variable expansion (during the processing of the same command).  If that's what you're trying to accomplish then you'll need to find a different way.

You can replace your curate function with:
curate() {
  local IFS= e=
  for e in /home/me/Downloads/$name.$1
  do
    [ -e "$e" ] && echo "$e"
  done
}

By localising IFS to empty string, glob expansion still happens but word-splitting of the result is disabled.
